# Returning from jumps

Tags: assembly

I am very new to assembly and I have a beginner's question. Suppose I compare something, then I do `je anotherLabel`. How can I make it return, after it finishes executing `anotherlabel`, to the line after `je anotherlabel` in the original one?

Example:

```
cmp ecx, '['
je it_is_open_bracket
cmp ecx, ']'
je it_is_close_bracket
```

and

```
it_is_open_bracket:
    dostuff
```

Now let us suppose the first `cmp` returns equal, then it executes `it_is_open_bracket`, how can I make it return after that to `cmp ecx, ']'`, thus completing the rest of the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  cmp ecx, '['
  jne notob
  call it_is_open_bracket
notob:
  cmp ecx, ']'
  jne notcb
  call it_is_close_bracket
notcb:
  ...
it_is_open_bracket:
  ...
  RET
```

is the classic way. Normally, you'd create a macro like `CE` to do the same thing - the precise syntax depends on the assembler you are using - but that would allow you to code

```
  cmp ecx, '['
  ce it_is_open_bracket
  cmp ecx, ']'
  ce it_is_close_bracket
```

with the macro doing the donkey-work.

Comment: Follow-up beginner question: After `it_is_open_bracket` returns, where does it return to exactly? `notob`?

Comment: The instruction directly following the `CALL`

Comment: Okay, I don't want it to do that, So I'll create another label for the the rest of the work routine, and jmp to it instead of returning from `it_is...`. When I did that (and when I applied the `classic` way you said), I suddenly began getting Segmentation faults.

Answer (score 4):

It would be easier for you that instead of jumping you implement a subroutine and call it using `CALL` then `RET` to go back where you were.

> call, ret — Subroutine call and return
>
> These instructions implement a subroutine call and return. The call instruction first pushes the current code location onto the
>   hardware supported stack in memory (see the push instruction for
>   details), and then performs an unconditional jump to the code location
>   indicated by the label operand. Unlike the simple jump instructions,
>   the call instruction saves the location to return to when the
>   subroutine completes.
>
> The ret instruction implements a subroutine return mechanism. This instruction first pops a code location off the hardware supported
>   in-memory stack (see the pop instruction for details). It then
>   performs an unconditional jump to the retrieved code location.
>
> ```
> Syntax
> call <label>
> ret
> ```

[Source](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html)

Comment: Yes, but how would I implement it so that it calls only if equal/above/under?

Comment: Use branch/jump to call or not.